# How can I make CRM 4.0 Internet Accessible?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, iis, configuration, crm

I have inherited a group of servers that I am now administrating full-time. We have a CRM 4.0 installation that is installed on one of the DCs in the local domain. The CRM database, however, is stored on the local domain's Exchange 2007 server box.

CRM works locally on the domain for all users, either via browser or the CRM Outlook Client. Outside of the company LAN, the CRM web portal will not resolve -- and presumably the Outlook client will not resolve either.

I assumed this was DNS, and I still think I was right on that originally. There was no authoritative server for the name that the box was using from behind the firewall (crm.ourdomain.com). Now that has been corrected, and I can reach CRM on the local domain using the browser with the NETBIOS name or even the full internet domain name (crm.ourdomain.com).

ourdomain.com is using Network Solutions for a NameServer. One of those entries is to a machine called crm.ourdomain.com which points to our public IP address. At the firewall, port 80 traffic is coming directly to the AD/DNS/CRM server -- but port 443 traffic is going to the Exchange server for OWA. Port 53 is open for DNS and pointing to the AD/DNS/CRM server.

The AD/DNS/CRM server is the SOA for the crm.icucare.com Zone. It has one (A) record that points to itself (i.e. AD/DNS/CRM server). The IIS configuration on that machine has an inetpub\wwwroot\crm folder that is bound to any traffic (80 or 443) on either of 2 statically set IPs (IPv4 addresses) assigned to it with bindings for crm.ourdomain.com and crm.ourdomain.local.

The CRM server also has an ourdomain.local (A) record with the same IP being used in the crm.ourdomain.com zone.

When I try to browse (outside of the LAN) to the site: ht tp://crm.ourdomain.com/ I immediately get a 404 error, but if I browse to ht tps://crm.ourdomain.com I get a blank page.

Any ideas at all? Sorry, I tried to be thorough enough to clear up any of those 'Check your DNS' replies, etc. Very desirable information includes what the IIS settings for CRM SHOULD look like.

Windows Server 2008 (CRM / Exchange) and Windows Server 2008 R2 (Backup DC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an update with a newer symptom, and a final solution:

(2) Things to Note:

Port 443 was being forwarded to a different machine -- which didn't help, but that wasn't the final solution.

Port 80 was being forwarded correctly, and after relaxing the bindings to send ALL HTTP:80 traffic to the CRM site, a funny thing started happening -- the URL would redirect to something like this:

http://crminstancename.crm.ourdomain.com/FileNotFound.aspx?file=/signin.aspx

And would do so with a 404 error.
This was the best hint at what was wrong.  I re-ran the CRM IFD Configuration Tool and changed the old IFD Root Domain from: crm.ourdomain.com to ourdomain.com. Then I changed the DNS from crm.ourdomain.com to crminstancename.ourdomain.com and updated the IIS bindings accordingly.

Now everything works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

In your IIS configuration for the CRM site there's probably host headers that need to be added/edited to match the new DNS names.

If you need any additional help with this, I work for a MS Partner specializing in CRM (among other products). We'd be glad to help.

Comment: The host headers are configured for 'crm' on port 80, and for 'crm.ourdomain.com' on port 443. Again, these work internally on our LAN, but for some reason there is some problem resolving from outside of the LAN. Thanks for the offer of help, though!